# JavaFX refreshing dynamically colored tableview

Tags: java, javafx, colors, tableview

I am building a JavaFX app with a TableView, and I want to it dynamically change color depending on different user selections. I can get it to initially populate with colored data, but refreshing it keeps original colors.

This is the basic functionality of my method that is called dynamically each time the user changes something:

```
SessionsTableView.getItems().clear();
ObservableList<SessionItem> newsessionitems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (SessionPart x : AllSessionParts) {
    tableitems.add(new SessionItem(count, x.name, x.getdurationasString(true, 150.0), getambiencetext(x), x.goals_getCurrentAsString(true, 150.0)));
    newsessionitems.add(x);
    count++;   
}
SessionsTableView.setItems(newsessionitems);
```

Methods return different String values which are tested in my cell value factory to determine color:

```
DurationColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<SessionItem, String>, TableCell<SessionItem, String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell<SessionItem, String> call(TableColumn<SessionItem, String> param) {
                    return new TableCell<SessionItem, String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (! isEmpty()) {
                                switch (item) {
                                    case "No Duration Set":
                                        setTextFill(Color.RED);
                                        break;
                                    case "Short Duration Set":
                                        setTextFill(Color.YELLOW);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                                        break;
                                }
                                setText(item);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
```

JavaFX colors the text based on the String values provided when initialially populated, but not when called again. My override of the updateitem(String, boolean) method is called, and the text values are changed, but the colors of even the changed text are not updated/refreshed.

How do I get the colors to change dynamically?

Comment: Seems like that should work (unrelated, but your cell should clear the text (`setText(null)`) if `isEmpty()` is true). You said you checked the `updateItem(...)` method is called and the item is changed, can you check if it is entering any of the `case` statements?

Comment: I agree it should work. Java isn't my first language and JavaFX isn't my first GUI I've built with so I'm still learning. For some reason it still doesn't work. I added a setText(null) if isEmpty() and it is entering the case statements as I added a string to check and it's entering each of the different cases correctly, and it is changing the text, but not the color.

Comment: Probably then you need to [edit] your question to include a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* and *complete*). I usually use a CSS approach for this, fwiw, but there's no obvious reason this approach won't work.

Comment: I tested your cell factory and it worked just fine for me. The issue is definitely caused by errors in other code you have written. So the question is not answerable without a [MCVE].

Comment: Did the colors also change for you? Everything else works for me but the color changes. Strangely enough it works fine for the changing the background, but using setTextFill() method to change the text color does not work. This is also a child stage class I extended, launched as a child to the Root pane could that affect my outcome?

Comment: Yes, the text color changed too. No-one can tell you what is wrong unless you make the effort to create a [MCVE], as described already.

Comment: Also the dialog is using showandWait(). And there are alot of animations running in the program and I know those two conflict. However, I have stopped all animations before launching this dialog. Can I not make this a modal dialog? It needs to be for modal my program design.

Comment: If only someone had told you a way to get your question answered.

Comment: No I understand you want a minimal example but I'm having a hard time extracting it due to the complexity of my program. I thought it might be a super easy something I missed about javafx being a newbie to javafx but it must be a different problem. I will try to test and solve it, and once I find the real issue, if I cannot solve it, I will present it here

Comment: Instead of extracting it, start with *just* the cell factory you have and build the smallest possible program that uses that. Then see if it works. If it does, try adding some of the other functionality from your real program until you break it. (Though, if it's not easy to extract parts of your application and test them independently, you should probably reconsider your coding design anyway.)

Comment: OK Thank you. I will try that. And I'm just a hobbyist developer building apps, I'm  not a professional and I haven't had any formal training or school in this, so my design probably isn't the best but I'm definitely learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of using the setTextFill() method which didn't work for me, I used setStyle("-fx-text-fill:"). This seemed to solve the problem. The table now dynamically refreshes as I intended it to.

```
DurationColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<SessionItem, String>, TableCell<SessionItem, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<SessionItem, String> call(TableColumn<SessionItem, String> param) {
                return new TableCell<SessionItem, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (! isEmpty()) {
                            switch (item) {
                                case "No Duration Set":
                                    setTextFill(Color.RED); // Doesn't Work
                                    setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red") // Does Work 
                                    break;

                            }
                            setText(item);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```